# Adding Reference in config file

Tags: asp.net, reference, web-config, app-config

Is there any way to keep the particular section of config file in another file and reference it?

```
 <configuration> 
    <appSettings>
        <add key="LogConfigXMLPath" value="D:\IIS_CODE\virtualworkspace\LogConfig.xml"/>
        <add key="ErrorLoggerName" value="ErrorLogger"/>
        <add key="CouchDBHost" value="ctsintbmvstcdb"/>
        <add key="CouchDBPort" value="5984"/>
        <add key="CouchDBBaseDatabase" value="virtualworkplace"/>
    </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Whether is there any possible way to reference this kind of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if you can reference the appSettings section from an external file then yes you can.

**External.config** file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogConfigXMLPath" value="D:\IIS_CODE\virtualworkspace\LogConfig.xml"/>
    <add key="ErrorLoggerName" value="ErrorLogger"/>
    <add key="CouchDBHost" value="ctsintbmvstcdb"/>
    <add key="CouchDBPort" value="5984"/>
    <add key="CouchDBBaseDatabase" value="virtualworkplace"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then, in your your **app.config** or **web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="C:\PathToYourExternalConfigFile\External.config">
        <add key="SomeAdditionalKey" value="Value1" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```